# Kubernetes pod keeps crashing with no error in logs

Tags: docker, kubernetes, terraform

I am trying to deploy apache docker image using Terraform on Kubernetes Cluster

I tried the following command and able to hit the URL `localhost:8082` from browser successfully

```
docker run -it --rm -d -p 8082:80 webservice
```

I then created a kubernetes_deployment using Terraform but pod keeps crashing and `there's nothing in logs`

```
resource "kubernetes_deployment" "api" {
  metadata {
    name = "ex-api"
    labels = {
      app       = "EX"
      component = "api"
    }
  }
  spec {
    replicas = 1
    selector {
      match_labels = {
        app = "EX"
      }
    }
    template {
      metadata {
        name = "ex-api"
        labels = {
          app       = "EX"
          component = "api"
        }
      }
      spec {
        container {
          image             = "${var.web_service_image}:${var.web_service_image_tag}"
          image_pull_policy = "IfNotPresent"
          name              = "api-image"

          # All the other configuration options should be here too.
          port {
            container_port = 80
            name           = "web"
          }
        }  # end of container block

      } # end of spec block
    } # end of template block
  } # end of spec out-block
}
```

Pod's output

```
kubectl get pod
NAME                      READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
ex-api-5458586bd8-ex6sp   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   19         72m
```

I assume I should either add some `command or daemonize` (eg -itd when using docker) it so that it keeps running.  I may be wrong here

Kindly let me know what should I do to overcome this

Comment: have you tried describe? kubectl describe po ex-api-5458586bd8-ex6sp sometimes you get some hints there

Comment: I tried that, but I did not see any error.  kubectl logs <podname> -p also did not produce any log

Comment: Your deployment needs to use the command that  you have in your Dockerfile.

Comment: Paste your Dockerfile, Deployment.yaml and the output of the describe command.

Comment: As you mentioned I added "command = [apache2-foreground]" to my kubernetes deployment and issue was resolved.  But, I don't understand why should we mention the command explicitly in K8S deployment, when docker image itself had 'apache2-foreground'.   Thanks for pointing out the mistake which helped me to fix the issue

Comment: have you tried --previous flag within your log command, it will show the previous log a pod created before terminating

Comment: @SathishKumar if you found a solution to your problem, please post it as an answer.

Comment: @PawełGrondal Solution was provided by Rakesh.  If he adds I can accept that as an answer.  I thought it will be unfair to claim credit for someone else knowledge

Answer (score 2):

No logs or no events shown when you run the describe command generally suggests that that there is an issue with invoking your entrypoint in your Dockerfile. So, you may have to overwrite the command  in your deployment.yaml

In your case - your deployment may need to use the command that you have or tried to use in your Dockerfile. Apparently, kubernetes pod is unable to use what you have defined in the Dockerfile.